terraform destroy needs original terraform code to destroy?
Does terraform need origial code to run terraform destroy?
i am deploying aws terraform into new aws accounts per client. My terraform is continuously evolving, and it seems when i want to destroy, i need the original terraform code to destroy?
I was hoping if i have access to backend s3 state, then by pointing to that backend and running terraform destroy(from anywhere, without having the original terraform, just having terragform binary), it should destroy everything. This seems to work most of the time. But for one of my infras i get this error:
Error: Provider configuration not present
│ 
│ To work with module.s3Module.aws_s3_bucket.this (orphan) its original
│ provider configuration at
│ module.s3Module.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"] is
│ required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider
│ configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist
│ in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
│ module.s3Module.aws_s3_bucket.this (orphan), after which you can remove the
│ provider configuration again

I am able to successfully destroy infra if i run destroy using the original terraform code, but this should be a common problem i am thinking. While my code is versioned and i can run destroy using the original version, i feel it should be more convinient than this. What am i missing?
Is there a way to get around this problem?
Lets say i deployed terraform code version v1.0, but my latest code is version v3.0 and i want to run destroy that doesnt depend on those versions. I created a gitlab pipeline that points to required s3 backend and runs destroy. this works most of the time but sometimes it complains about providers.

Do I understand correctly that you're running a destroy with a configuration that is not represented in your state file, rather than running an init with the new config and then a plan or apply to see which old resources will be destroyed and which new ones will be created?

Short answer - yes. Terraform commands are executed against Terraform code, not against state files. State files are noting more then a "by-product" used to track the latest applied configuration.
Long answer - probably not necessarily. While I have no experience with your particular need (although I did have to manually update my state files on more then 1 occasion), quick Google search led me to this answer:
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/destroying-resources-with-state-file-only/31833/3
There are different 2 approaches mentioned in the above forum post. I'd personally be probably more inclined to use the seconds mentioned approach of simply creating an empty main.tf file configured to use your backend (where your state file lays) and run the destroy command agains this empty TF config.
To quote the mentioned post:

To make it simple for future reference. Just create a terraform
configuration with a local backend pointing to that state file. E.g.
In main.tf:
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path="your_statefile_here.json"
  }
}

You can hopefully then terraform init and terraform destroy as usual.


The spelling is "by-product" or "byproduct" with a y https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By-product

@MarkB farming points, are we?  you're right though  updated

You don't get points on this site for comments. So no, I'm not "farming points".

Using only a backend configuration will not work unless you either have no resource instances tracked in the state (in which case destroying would be pointless) or all of the providers you are using can pick up the necessary configuration information from ambient sources like environment variables. (Disclaimer: I am apparentlymart in that forum so I wrote the first answer that I think is the more complete answer, and doesn't disagree with the later one.)

thanks @PatrikŠimunič , Your answer and the link you provided helped me find what i was missing. i had one module which had separate provider defined, this is the one that was complaining about provider. So i removed that provider config. I wonder what are the disadvantages of not defining providers separately. At this point i have defined providers only once in the main code. And this is working for me exaclty as i wanted.

You can first run terraform apply so terraform will reflect your code changes in state file. And then run terraform destroy to remove all your resources.

Thanks for this, this is what i was doing, when i was having issues while using a generic destroy ... but now its working for me as i wanted. I have explained what i did in another comment.
